Word embeddings with a constrained loss variational autoencoder
I got an idea while refreshing some knowledge about CBOW and Skip-Gram. I thought to post here to receive some criticism and perhaps learn something new.
The idea was to use a basic Variational Autoencoder which takes one token at a time as input - but has an additional loss function which says that each token vector representation should be a vector sum (add each component) of the tokens that came before within a window, i.e.: three tokens that come before.
As a toy example, lets say that will have a 2-dimensional embedding. This means that the latent space will have two nodes for the z-mean (the final mean values will be our embeddings).
A training data point, to continue the example, will be this sentence from the movie review dataset:
sample_text = "For a movie that gets no respect there sure are a lot of memorable quotes listed for this gem."    

If the window is set to three then,

"for" has no prior token
"a" should be equal to "for"
"movie" should be "for" + "a"
"that" should be "for" + "a" + "movie"
"gets" should be "a" + "movie" + "that", and so on.

So for each, token in a training sentence/paragraph data we have three terms in the loss: kl, reconstruction, and the vector addition term i, j since we only have two dimensions.
The plot for the sentence above looks like this after a couple of epochs:

As I expected, words like "a", "for", "there" which are pretty common will have very small values because they don't explain much - but other words like "gem" or "quotes" have much higher values. So, it looks like it is somewhat working although the constraint might be very naive. Also, it may be possible to add different constraint through the different dimensions, etc.
I would love to hear any opinions or criticism - or if someone knows any actual similar work. I am not a researcher - just an enthusiast.
